# Two sites on one server: NameVirtualHost site2 has no VirtualHosts

Tags: django, apache2

I have two web sites developed with Django framework and I've tried to get them reachable from the same machine with virtual host configuration in Apache2.
I have created **/etc/apache2/sites-available/alcs**:

```
NameVirtualHost alcs:80
<VirtualHost alcs:80>
    ServerAdmin candini@meeo.it
    ServerName alcs
    DocumentRoot /home/candini/Repos/ALCS/SW/alcs-system/GUI-User-Interface
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/candini/Repos/ALCS/SW/alcs-system/GUI-User-Interface/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/candini/Repos/ALCS/SW/alcs-system/GUI-User-Interface/apache/django.wsgi
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and **/etc/apache2/sites-available/jsonopenlayers**:

```
NameVirtualHost jsonopenlayers:80
<VirtualHost jsonopenlayers:80>
    ServerAdmin candini@meeo.it
    ServerName jsonopenlayers
    DocumentRoot /home/candini/Repos/CanetaRepo/tmp/STO
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/candini/Repos/CanetaRepo/tmp/STO/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/candini/Repos/CanetaRepo/tmp/STO/apache/django.wsgi
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I have made the following:

```
echo "127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost jsonopenlayers alcs" >> /etc/hosts
a2ensite alcs
a2ensite jsonopenlayers
/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

But the problem is that I get:

```
root@office-007:~# /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
* Restarting web server apache2 [Mon Dec 12 11:23:26 2011] [warn] NameVirtualHost jsonopenlayers:80 has no VirtualHosts
[Mon Dec 12 11:23:26 2011] [warn] NameVirtualHost jsonopenlayers:80 has no VirtualHosts
... waiting [Mon Dec 12 11:23:27 2011] [warn] NameVirtualHost jsonopenlayers:80 has no VirtualHosts
[Mon Dec 12 11:23:27 2011] [warn] NameVirtualHost jsonopenlayers:80 has no VirtualHosts
```

Only alcs site is properly reached at http://localhost/alcs. If I try to reach the second one I get the following Django error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost/jsonopenlayers/

Using the URLconf defined in python_scripts.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^alcs/
^alcs/evolution_model_catalogue.html
^alcs/advanced_search_option.html
^alcs/ontological_tree_cascade.html
^alcs/search_evolution_model.html
^alcs/load_evolution_model.json
^alcs/select_load_option.html
^alcs/delete_model.json
^alcs/withdraw_model.json
^alcs/evolution_model_catalogue.html
^alcs/support_request.json
^alcs/malfunction_report.json
^alcs/file_upload.html
^alcs/malfunction_file_upload

The current URL, jsonopenlayers/, didn't match any of these.
```

But it works without problems if I delete alcs link from **/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/** directory.

Where my configuration is wrong?

Comment: If you want your sites on `localhost/sitename`, why are you mucking around with named hosts? That has nothing to do with it at all.

Comment: Yes, I just want my sites to be reachable at http://localhost/alcs and http://localhost/jsonopenlayers. So how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments, named hosts is completely the wrong way to go about this. Named hosts are exactly that - when you want to serve several different domain names from the same machine. So if you wanted to serve foo.com and bar.com from the same Apache, you would use this.

What you want is something different, and much simpler: just to serve two Django sites off separate sub-folders in the same domain. You can do that with just two lines:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /alcs/ /home/candini/Repos/ALCS/SW/alcs-system/GUI-User-Interface/apache/django.wsgi
WSGIScriptAlias /jsonopenlayers/ /home/candini/Repos/CanetaRepo/tmp/STO/apache/django.wsgi
```